# How to add javascript to HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to web development and I want to add following function to my simple html page but if I press "click me" does not happen anything. description part does not hide and show

[This is the code I tried](http://jsfiddle.net/wGbh5/)

I added those codes as below. CSS is working perfectly. but JavaScript does not work. How can I fix this issue

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hpcss.css">
<script>
// Hide all the elements in the DOM that have a class of "box"
$('.box').hide();

// Make sure all the elements with a class of "clickme" are visible and bound
// with a click event to toggle the "box" state
$('.clickme').each(function() {
    $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
        // This is only needed if your using an anchor to target the "box" elements
        e.preventDefault();

        // Find the next "box" element in the DOM
        $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
</script>


</head>
<body align="center">
<a href="#" class="clickme">Click Me</a>
<div class="box">
    First Description
</div>

<a href="#" class="clickme">Click Me</a>
<div class="box">
    Second Description
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is your issue.The fiddle seem to be working fine

Comment: Div tag does not hide and show... I added to javascript to <head> tag. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do somethings like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // add your code here
})
```

you run javascript before finishing load html --> error

Comment: the questioner says with the above answer his problem is solved , then why it gets down votes?

Comment: This is wrong. The fact that it works is irrelevant. The answer says "you run javascript before finishing load html", which is incorrect. Javascript is not jQuery. jQuery is a library that is written in Javascript.

Answer (score 5):

You need to import jQuery, and only run the code once jQuery has loaded

**HTML**:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

**JS**:

```
$(function() {
    // your code here
})
```

The fiddle is working because `jsfiddle` automatically runs on DOM load, and inserts `jQuery` for you.

here is the actual source from `jsfiddle` (behind the scenes):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
// Hide all the elements in the DOM that have a class of "box"
$('.box').hide();

// Make sure all the elements with a class of "clickme" are visible and bound
// with a click event to toggle the "box" state
$('.clickme').each(function() {
    $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
        // This is only needed if your using an anchor to target the "box" elements
        e.preventDefault();

        // Find the next "box" element in the DOM
        $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});

});//]]>  

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

embed this before your script.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your js code into

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        // your code will be here       
    });
</script>
```

It means that your code will be executed after page elements are loaded.
Also I'v added jquery include.

Answer (score 0):

You attach the events before the DOM is created. When you're calling

```
// Make sure all the elements with a class of "clickme" are visible and bound
// with a click event to toggle the "box" state
$('.clickme').each(function() {
    $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
        // This is only needed if your using an anchor to target the "box" elements
        e.preventDefault();

        // Find the next "box" element in the DOM
        $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

The elements with the `clickme` class have not been created yet.

You can fix it by putting your script tags before the `</body>` tag, but by wrapping your javascript in a self-executing function like so:

```
$(function()
{
    // Hide all the elements in the DOM that have a class of "box"
    $('.box').hide();

    // Make sure all the elements with a class of "clickme" are visible and bound
    // with a click event to toggle the "box" state
    $('.clickme').each(function() {
        $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
        // This is only needed if your using an anchor to target the "box" elements
            e.preventDefault();

            // Find the next "box" element in the DOM
            $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

Also, you're not including the jQuery library.

Always check the console for errors.